# Need help to identify ZNR

Tags: components

I have a cooked component that I believe to be a ZNR since it is labled JNR01J and is in series with a 125V T2A fuse. It is from an air conditioner PCB. It was cooked while using a portable generator (also cooked the cable box and 1 power strip).

I can't find any cross reference to this component. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The part is a surge absorber as Russell says, the code on the part in the image brings up the [datasheet](http://www.samwhatech.co.kr/product/datasheet/varistor/Disk.pdf).

The code is SVC 271-14, where SVC means it's a zinc varistor, the 271 stands for a nominal voltage of 270V, and the 14 means it's 14mm in diameter.
So any peaks past 270V should be suppressed, which sounds about right for a 240V system. The typical I-V curve is given on page 45.

Comment: Really appreciate all your help. I have all the information I need.

Comment: @Stan, feel free to accept this answer (green checkmark) if you have found it to answer your question - the FAQ has information on this too.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:  As an appliance repair this does not belong here. As a "how to do it right" it should be useful for designers and others.**

Presumably you mean it is labelled ZNR01J and did not check for typos ?

Giving model and brand helps heaps.

Presumably it is NOT in series with a fuse but rather is connected from the non-mains side of a mains fuse to either ground or the other mains lead.

The diagram below probably shows a similar arrangement - see component labelled ZNR01J. That diagram and others like it [from LG service manual here](http://www.appliancefactoryparts.com/content/pdfs/118524.pdf) - see eg page 20.

This component is liable to be a MOV or Varistor or ZNR = surge suppressor.

The LG manual lists it as a SVC271D-14A.
[Datasheet here](http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/132747/ETC1/SVC271D-14A.html) - in a frame but PDF can be saved.

Note that **this may not be the correct part** as I HAVE assumed information that you have available and could have supplied but didn't. And I have corrected what appears to be an error in your data - but which may not be, and corrected your circuit description, possibly wrongly.  More information (and possibly more care) at the start (brand, model, circuit, better description of where it really was electrically in the circuit, non-typo in part number (a biggie if true), link to ZNR's etc) would help muchly.

Page 47:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The unit is a Sears Kenmore Model 58070122000 which I believe is manufactured by LG. I appologize for the typo - it is ZNR01J on the schematic not JNR01J. The diagram you posted is different than that of my unit but appears fundamentally the same.

Comment: The data sheet I pointed to will be adequate. Essentially, any MOV or similar intended for use on that role will be liable to do an OK job.